# Showing a spinning wheel in the foreground while my task executes in the UI thread

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app which writes into an excel sheet, when I click on a button (View), and when it finishes it shows a dialog box which informs me that the task is completed .

Currently, when I press the button view, it shows the button in the "clicked" state until the report is generated. I would like to show a spinning wheel (indefinite progress bar case) in the foreground of the screen for the time from the moment I press the button to just before the dialog box shows up. Can someone explain with code how I should do this?

I am meddling with the runnable class ( new thread creation) but not getting any result.

Comment: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a pretty easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Click event start an **AsyncTask**

```
new NewAsyncTask(ClassName.this).execute();
```

**NewAsyncTask.java**

```
 public class NewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
 {
  private ProgressDialog mDialog;

  Context mCntxt;

  public NewAsyncTask(Context context) 
     {
    mCntxt = context;
     }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    new ProgressDialog(mCntxt);
    mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mCntxt, "", "Loading..");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
  //code for writing excel sheet
   return "success";

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
    if(mDialog!=null && mDialog.isShowing())
    {
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
    if (result.length()>0) 
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(mCntxt)
    .setTitle("")
    .setMessage("")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK"),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    .create().show();
    }

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Mobile for pageLoading. The following link should help

[Jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/api/methods.html)